# Insert Row and Update the same row In PHP / MYSQL simultaneously

Tags: php

Please help me with this:

I am creating a survey facility for the administrator. The administrator is asked for the number of questions in the questionnaire. And based on this the rows are created in the survey details table. In the question table the corresponding number of rows are created for the same in the question table.

Now the admin can enter the questions and answers. For this I need to insert the row in question table and update it from the informations collected from FORM using a loop. But the inserted rows are not getting updated simultaneously. Help me with this or is there any other way to do this?

This is my code: Please ignore the programming style as this is the script by a novice:

```
$sid = intval ($_GET['ids']);
$noq = intval ($_GET['qn']);
for($noq !=0;$noq >=1;$noq--){  
    $q = "insert into sur_ques (sur_id) values ('$sid')";
    $ex = mysql_query($q);
    $rs = mysql_affected_rows();
    if($rs ==1){ echo" Questions Rows Created Corresponding to Survey Subject";}
?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo($PHP_SELF); ?>">
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tr><br><b>Ques No-<?php echo"$noq";?></b></tr><br>
    <tr><textarea name = "q" rows ="10" cols = "70" wrap = "hard" ></textarea></tr><br>
    <tr><td><b>Ans 1:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="a1" size="37" /></td></tr>   
    <tr><td><b>Ans 2:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="a2" size="37"  /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Ans 3:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="a3" size="37"  /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Ans 4:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="a4" size="37" /></td></tr>
</table>
<input type = "submit" name="qa" Value = "Add Q&A" />
<input type ="reset" Value="Reset" />
</form> 
<?
    if ($_POST['qa']){
        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        $result = mysql_query("update ques set q_txt = '$q', ans1 = '$a1' ans2 = '$a2'  ans4 = '$a4' ans4 = '$a4' where q_id = '$id'");
        if($r = mysql_num_rows($result)){
            echo" Question and answers updated";
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You cannot insert and update simultaneously, one query will have to finish executing before another can start.

Comment: What is the point and inserting and updating the same row? There's no. You might be interested in MySQL triggers.

Comment: Triggers can solve your problem

Comment: Or search insert--replace mysql syntax

Comment: BTW try to use proper tags, like you should have used mysql, insert etc tags also in your question. Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

I dont get you .. may be you can put more info like table structure so that i can understand it well.

but one thing for sure you can not update and insert row simultaneously... you will have to insert row into database in order to update row.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is mysql_insert_id.

```
session_start();
$q = "INSERT INTO table (id,key1,key2) VALUES (null,'value1','value2')";
$r = mysql_query($q);
$_SESSION['rowid'] = mysql_insert_id();
```

then subsequent queries would do:

```
$sq = "UPDATE table SET key='value',secondkey='secondvalue', WHERE id=$_SESSION['rowid'] ";
$sr = mysql_query($sq);
```

I don't see the need for a loop when you can insert/update as many columnsas you need in one go as you can see above. Doing it like this you will never need to insert and update at the same time (which is impossible), because you simply start the record with whatever info is available, or even if no info is available, you create an empty row, store the id and then update the row as new infomration becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

"In the question table the corresponding number of rows are created for the same in the question table." - did you mean questions and answers?

Well you have a form, you have two type of inputs (questions[] and answers[]), then in cycle you just insert a question and a corresponding answer text (based on input's key) and connect them (answer should have quesitonID or vise versa, depending on what you insert first and what type of multiplicity connection is between them.. i guess question can have multiple answers)